# How to groupby 2 columns but order descending by count()

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, count, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe and want to group 2 columns, which is working fine.

```
df.groupby(["Sektor, CustomerID"]).count().head(10)
```

```
            _Order_ID_  Order_timezone  Order_weight                                
AE  1298772       1         1                1  
    1298788       1         1                1  
    1298840       2         2                2  
    1298912       1         1                1

AT  1038570       1         1                1  
    1040424       1         1                1  
    1040425       3         3                3  
    1040426       2         2                2  
    1040427       1         1                1  
    1040428       1         1                1  
    1040429       2         2                2
```

Now the grouped dataframe is sorted by the CustomerID values. But i want to sort it by the count(). So that i have the Sektor then the CustomerIDs but the CustomerIds that occure the most should be at the top. So descending.

Expected Output should be:

```
            _Order_ID_  Order_timezone  Order_weight                                
AE  1298840       2         2                2
    1298772       1         1                1  
    1298788       1         1                1      
    1298912       1         1                1

AT  1040425       3         3                3
    1040426       2         2                2
    1040429       2         2                2
    1038570       1         1                1  
    1040424       1         1                1          
    1040427       1         1                1  
    1040428       1         1                1
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Sektor", "CustomerID"]).count()
```

If need 10 rows in ouput:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Sektor','_Order_ID_'], ascending=[True, False]).head(10)
print (df1)
                   _Order_ID_  Order_timezone  Order_weight
Sektor CustomerID                                          
AE     1298840              2               2             2
       1298772              1               1             1
       1298788              1               1             1
       1298912              1               1             1
AT     1040425              3               3             3
       1040426              2               2             2
       1040429              2               2             2
       1038570              1               1             1
       1040424              1               1             1
       1040427              1               1             1
```

If need 10 rows (if exist) per groups by `Sektor`:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Sektor','_Order_ID_'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('Sektor').head(10)
print (df1)
                   _Order_ID_  Order_timezone  Order_weight
Sektor CustomerID                                          
AE     1298840              2               2             2
       1298772              1               1             1
       1298788              1               1             1
       1298912              1               1             1
AT     1040425              3               3             3
       1040426              2               2             2
       1040429              2               2             2
       1038570              1               1             1
       1040424              1               1             1
       1040427              1               1             1
       1040428              1               1             1
```

Comment: It says missing argument "by". So if i use one of the other parameters, then Sektor is not combined anymore. So e.g. i have 29 Orders from one Customer ID in Sektor A, but 20 Orders from a Customer ID in Sektor A, that is now not anymore in grouped Sektor A but in a seperate Sektor A a few rows lower.

Comment: @Russgo - Can you ad some data sample? Because if use `df.groupby(["Sektor, CustomerID"])` it means grouping by combinations of both columns.

Comment: @Russgo - Or need second part my answer?

Comment: I edited my post. The DataFrame looks like this after grouping. When i use your two ideas, the grouping is dissolved.

Comment: Nop it is still sorting by the "Customer_iD".

Comment: Its not working the ascending statement always goes on the "Customer_iD"

Comment: @Russgo - Tested and working very well, for you not?

Comment: @Russgo - No, you are wrong, because sorting by `Sektor` and `_Order_ID_`, not by `CustomerID`. But if all values in `_Order_ID_` are same per `Sector` it seems it is sorted by `CustomerID`

Comment: Sorry man, i had a typo. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Could you please tell me what the [True, False] statement does exactly?

Comment: @Russgo - It means sorting by `Sektor` ascendant (True) and by `_Order_ID_` descendant (False). List of columns `['Sektor','_Order_ID_']` are matched by list of sorting `[True, False]`